# Converting YUV to RGB in Python, coefficients work with Array, don't work with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, rgb, yuv

The following code takes a raw YUV image and converts it to RGB using Array manipulation and takes forever.

```
from PIL import Image
from struct import *
import array
 
 
image_name = "frame2.raw" #Change to user input
width = int(3864) #Assumed to be static
height = int(2192) #Assumed to be static

y = array.array('B')  #B unsigned Char, I is unsigned int
u = array.array('B')  #The raw file is unsigned int 8
v = array.array('B')
 
f_y = open(image_name, "rb")
f_uv = open(image_name, "rb")
f_uv.seek(width*height, 1) #Change position of File handle seek(offset, from)
 
image_out = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
pix = image_out.load()
 
for i in range(0, height//2): #Run height/2 times
    for j in range(0, width//2): #Run width/2 times for each height count
        u.append(ord(f_uv.read(1)));   #append adds to the end of the array; Ord returns the Unicode
        v.append(ord(f_uv.read(1)));   #read byte by byte
 
for i in range(0,height): #Run height times
    for j in range(0, width): #Run width times for each height count
        y.append(ord(f_y.read(1))); #build y byte by byte in unicode from f_y
        Y_val = y[(i*width)+j]
        U_val = u[((i//2)*(width//2))+(j//2)]
        V_val = v[((i//2)*(width//2))+(j//2)]
        B = 1.164 * (Y_val-16) + 2.018 * (U_val - 128)
        G = 1.164 * (Y_val-16) - 0.813 * (V_val - 128) - 0.391 * (U_val - 128)
        R = 1.164 * (Y_val-16) + 1.596*(V_val - 128)
        pix[j, i] = int(R), int(G), int(B) 
 
######################################################
# B = 1.164(Y - 16)                   + 2.018(U - 128)
# G = 1.164(Y - 16) - 0.813(V - 128) - 0.391(U - 128)
# R = 1.164(Y - 16) + 1.596(V - 128)
######################################################
 
image_out.save("out.bmp")
```

But produces an accurate image:
[Output from Array based code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E3Hb.jpg)
[image]

In trying to make it more efficient I switched over to NumPy using the same coefficients for the color conversion.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
 
 
image_name = "frame2.raw" #Change to user input
width = int(3864) #Assumed to be static
height = int(2192) #Assumed to be static
y_end = width*height

yuv = np.fromfile(image_name, dtype='uint8')

y = yuv[0:y_end].reshape(height,width)
u = yuv[y_end::2].reshape(height//2, width//2)
v = yuv[y_end+1::2].reshape(height//2, width//2)

#y = y.astype(y.dtype) -16
#u = u.astype(u.dtype) -128
#v = v.astype(v.dtype) -128
u = u.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
v = v.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)

y = y.reshape((y.shape[0], y.shape[1], 1))
u = u.reshape((u.shape[0], u.shape[1], 1))
v = v.reshape((v.shape[0], v.shape[1], 1))

yuv_array = np.concatenate((y, u, v), axis=2)

yuv_array[:, :, 0] = yuv_array[:, :, 0].clip(16, 235).astype(yuv_array.dtype) - 16
yuv_array[:, :, 1:] = yuv_array[:, :, 1:].clip(16, 240).astype(yuv_array.dtype) - 128

convert = np.array([#[1.164,  0.000,  1.793],[1.164, -0.213, -0.533],[1.164,  2.112,  0.000]
                    [1.164,  0.000,  2.018], [1.164, -0.813, -0.391],[1.164,  1.596,  0.000]
                   ])
rgb = np.matmul(yuv_array, convert.T).clip(0,255).astype('uint8')


rgb_image = Image.fromarray(rgb)

rgb_image.save('numpyout.bmp')
```

However the output is now:
[Output from NumPy based code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9trkx.jpg)
[image]

I'm confident it's something simple I am overlooking, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Link to Original File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxCktABW1Q0SuUpDrQLi2jd0WS6juVfN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share the raw input file for folks to experiment with - maybe use Dropbox or Google Drive. Also its width and height.

Comment: Width: 3864 and Height is 2192.   [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxCktABW1Q0SuUpDrQLi2jd0WS6juVfN/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is **arithmetic overflow**.

Take a look at the following line of code:

```
yuv_array[:, :, 1:] = yuv_array[:, :, 1:].clip(16, 240).astype(yuv_array.dtype) - 128
```

- `yuv_array.dtype` is `uint8`.
  Subtracting 128 value from `uint8` elements results arithmetic overflow for all values below 128.
  Example:
  `np.array([100, 100], np.uint8) - 128` returns `array([228, 228], dtype=uint8)` (instead of `[-28, -28]`).

---

Solution:
Convert `yuv_array` to `float32` before subtraction:

```
yuv_array = yuv_array.astype(np.float32)
yuv_array[:, :, 0] = yuv_array[:, :, 0].clip(16, 235) - 16
yuv_array[:, :, 1:] = yuv_array[:, :, 1:].clip(16, 240) - 128
```

---

Complete code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
 
 
image_name = "frame2.raw" #Change to user input
width = int(3864) #Assumed to be static
height = int(2192) #Assumed to be static
y_end = width*height

yuv = np.fromfile(image_name, dtype='uint8')

y = yuv[0:y_end].reshape(height,width)
u = yuv[y_end::2].reshape(height//2, width//2)
v = yuv[y_end+1::2].reshape(height//2, width//2)

u = u.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
v = v.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)

y = y.reshape((y.shape[0], y.shape[1], 1))
u = u.reshape((u.shape[0], u.shape[1], 1))
v = v.reshape((v.shape[0], v.shape[1], 1))

yuv_array = np.concatenate((y, u, v), axis=2)

# Overflow: yuv_array.dtype = 'uint8', so subtracting 128 overflows.
#yuv_array[:, :, 0] = yuv_array[:, :, 0].clip(16, 235).astype(yuv_array.dtype) - 16
#yuv_array[:, :, 1:] = yuv_array[:, :, 1:].clip(16, 240).astype(yuv_array.dtype) - 128

# Convert from uint8 to float32 before subtraction
yuv_array = yuv_array.astype(np.float32)
yuv_array[:, :, 0] = yuv_array[:, :, 0].clip(16, 235) - 16
yuv_array[:, :, 1:] = yuv_array[:, :, 1:].clip(16, 240) - 128


convert = np.array([#[1.164,  0.000,  1.793],[1.164, -0.213, -0.533],[1.164,  2.112,  0.000]
                    [1.164,  0.000,  2.018], [1.164, -0.813, -0.391],[1.164,  1.596,  0.000]
                   ])
rgb = np.matmul(yuv_array, convert.T).clip(0,255).astype('uint8')


rgb_image = Image.fromarray(rgb)

rgb_image.save('numpyout.bmp')
```

---

Testing:

- Convert JPEG image from RGB to NV12 format using FFmpeg:
  `ffmpeg -i rgb.jpg -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt nv12 -f rawvideo frame2.raw`
  (We need it only because we don't have the original `frame2.raw` file).
- Execute the updated code.

---

`rgb_image` (down-sampled):
[image]

---

Note:
The YUV to RGB conversion matrix you are using applies BT.601 format.
It is more likely, that your input format applies BT.709 format.

Comment: Nicely sleuthed! You have my vote

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I added a link to the original .raw file so everyone can have some closure.  I will check on the formats, thank you again